# Symfony 2 persistence collection form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, persistence

I have a problem with a collection form that i can't understand.
I have followed the symfony cookbook on the form collection : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook ... tions.html

Almost all works fine, Jquery generates new items, they have all a different id.
During the first submission of the form, it works well. Doctrine does all correctly.

When i try to add new items, (new submission of the form), current items are replaced instead of being created in database.

I have added the "by reference" option and set it to false in order to force the call of method AddItem() but seems not to be called.
Doctrine only updated the collection if the number of new items is smaller.
When there are more items than the current objects in database, only the difference is added.

Best Regards